# Do I need to compile definition files alongside Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm not sure about this one, but do I need to compile my typings alongside typescript and have them compiled to same path as the were in originally.

if yes why, and similarly if no than why not?

I'm new to Typescript and so far been using typings with an approach where I thought they were just used for IDE to not throw errors, but now I am not so sure, as I have seen some posts talking about compiling these.

Comment: What do you mean by typings?

Comment: @Pablo I think `.d.ts` files.

Comment: @Pablo .d.ts files i.e. typings for jQuery: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

As long as you reference the types and variables defined in a .d.ts file, you have to keep it there in order to have a clean build. If you move around the file, do update the reference to reflect that. Think of a .d.ts file as a extension to the compiler.

You could just define "pretend" interfaces on your .ts file defining the names you're using, but that will clutter your main files with code that is not translated into anything.